# iPhone Map: Distinguishing Users Location from Other Pins

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I have a number of annotations on my map, in addition to the users current location. This works fine, except the default color for the users current location is the same as all of the other annotations. I'd like to make the pin green for the users current location so that it's uniquely identifiable from the other pins. How do I do this?

Bellow is the method I've been using (I can't find a way to determine which annotation is the users current location):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewLocal viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Pin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use standard `MKUserLocation` type for user location then you can check annotation's type if it is the same:

```
...
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){
// This is annotation for user location
}
```